# Independent or dependent

Tags: t-test

first read the scenario
A large insurance company is considering introducing a more complex procedure for processing claims. It is expected that the new processing procedure will increase claim processing times.
Before adopting the new approach, one company office decides to make duplicate copies of a random sample of 8 claims from its customers and have one set processed using the standard procedure and the duplicate claim processed with the new procedure.
now I am confused whether the sample is independent or dependent?
from my point of view, duplicate copies of a random sample of 8 claims were taken, and one set was processed using the standard procedure, while the duplicate claims were processed using the new procedure. There is no inherent relationship or dependence between the processing times of the two sets, as the values in the real set reveal no information about the duplicate sample
but still confused as some of my classmates are voting for dependent samples

Answer (score 1):

The samples are paired. If the only data you have are what you've said, then you can do a paired t-test or, if the assumptions are violated, a paired Wilcoxon.

If you have other data, you may want a multilevel model.

Dependent data means data where the samples are *different* but depend on each other. E.g. Data on husbands and wives in marriages, or left and right hands, or similar.

It's confusing because your *errors* are dependent, but I would not say your data is. And independent errors are a common assumption of many models.